# Weaknesses of AES-GCM

Tags: encryption, aes, aes-gcm

Besides the limited nonce size of 96 bits, are there any other weaknesses to the GCM mode of AES?

I am creating a password vault and am trying to narrow down my options of encryption schemes.

Also, is this a safe and secure implementation of AES-GCM?

```
public static async Task<byte[]> EncryptAsyncV2(byte[] plainText, byte[] password, byte[] nonce, byte[] salt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (plainText == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(plainText));
            if (password == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(password));
            if (salt == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(salt));
            if (nonce == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(nonce));

            var cipherText = new byte[plainText.Length];
            var tag = new byte[TagLen];

            using (var argon2 = new Argon2id(password))
            {
                argon2.Salt = salt;
                argon2.DegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
                argon2.Iterations = Iterations;
                argon2.MemorySize = (int)MemorySize;

                var key = await argon2.GetBytesAsync(KeySize);

                using var aesGcm = new AesGcm(key, TagLen);
                aesGcm.Encrypt(nonce, plainText, cipherText, tag);
                Array.Clear(key, 0, key.Length);
            }

            cipherText = tag.Concat(nonce.Concat(cipherText)).ToArray();
            return cipherText;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Array.Clear(password, 0, password.Length);
            ErrorLogging.ErrorLog(ex);
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            Array.Clear(password, 0, password.Length);
            ErrorLogging.ErrorLog(ex);
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Array.Clear(password!, 0, password!.Length);
            ErrorLogging.ErrorLog(ex);
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
        }
    }

    public static async Task<byte[]> DecryptAsyncV2(byte[] cipherText, byte[] password, byte[] salt)
    {
        try
        {
            if (cipherText == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(cipherText));
            if (password == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(password));
            if (salt == null)
                throw new ArgumentException(@"Value was empty or null.", nameof(salt));

            using var argon2 = new Argon2id(password);
            argon2.Salt = salt;
            argon2.DegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount * 2;
            argon2.Iterations = Iterations;
            argon2.MemorySize = (int)MemorySize;

            var key = await argon2.GetBytesAsync(KeySize);

            using var aesGcm = new AesGcm(key, TagLen);
            var tag = new byte[TagLen];
            var nonce = new byte[NonceSize];
            var cipherResult = new byte[cipherText.Length - nonce.Length - tag.Length];

            Buffer.BlockCopy(cipherText, 0, tag, 0, tag.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(cipherText, tag.Length, nonce, 0, nonce.Length);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(cipherText, tag.Length + nonce.Length, cipherResult, 0, cipherResult.Length);

            var plainText = new byte[cipherResult.Length];

            aesGcm.Decrypt(nonce, cipherResult, tag, plainText);

            Array.Clear(key, 0, key.Length);

            return plainText;
        }
        catch (CryptographicException ex)
        {
            Array.Clear(password, 0, password.Length);
            ErrorLogging.ErrorLog(ex);
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
        }
        catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
        {
            Array.Clear(password, 0, password.Length);
            ErrorLogging.ErrorLog(ex);
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Array.Clear(password!, 0, password!.Length);
            ErrorLogging.ErrorLog(ex);
            return Array.Empty<byte>();
        }
#pragma warning restore
    }
```

The nonce is generated with the RandomNumberGenerator class using this method

```
public static byte[] RndByteSized(int size)
    {
        var buffer = new byte[size];
        RndNum.GetBytes(buffer);
        return buffer;
    }
```

Comment: Start from here. [What are the rules for using AES-GCM correctly?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/84357/18298). You may choose AES-GCM-SIV to reduce the IV reuse problem under the same key. Note that it is better if you write down you requirements instead of asking one by one!

Comment: My requirements are basically I’m looking for the most secure encryption class. I’ve seen about gcm-siv but I don’t think I’ve seen any implementation of it in .net

Comment: There is no such option. AFAIK, for such an application you can live with AES-GCM or [xChaCha20-Poly1305 which has 192-bit nonce](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/87347/18298) that you can use random nonces for a long time.

Comment: What do you think about aes-cbc-hmac?

Comment: I wanted to use xchacha20 but I could not figure out how to get it working. I was getting encryption errors, I wasn’t sure how to get the nonce and tag to append to the ciphertext

Comment: You can use that, too, however your risk and requirement are not clear! For the programming issues ask at [so] with proper tags.

Comment: I’ve posted there and my questions keep getting closed due to them being “opinionated”. I’m basically looking for the most secure method of encryption with the least amount of vulnerabilities

Comment: We are not reviewing codes here. There is [so] and [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/270139/185475) for that purposes.

Comment: Like I said, stack overflow keeps closing my questions on bs grounds. Looks like asking here was equally as useless, I’ll try codereview. If I can’t get help there then I won’t bother anymore

Comment: Remember that Codereview requires running code not a place to find errors etc.

Comment: "most secure" is not universal. Security requires confidentiality, integrity, and availability. There are lots of cases where protocol design means AES-GCM is secure. There are other cases where it's not, e.g. where unique IVs can't be reasonably guaranteed. XChaCha20-Poly1305 is secure in more cases, though still not all (you can't publish the key publicly, for example). But XChaCha20-Poly1305 is slower than AES-GCM on many systems, so the "availability" portion of security is reduced (easier DOS attack). Without the requirements security cannot be judged.

Comment: I've actually asked this question myself before that one, [all the way back in 2013](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/10775/1172).